# Elasticsearch 5: aggregation on property values of latest n items

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate (sum) values of n latest items in Elasticsearch.

I tried "top-hits" (sorted by a date field), but I couldn't get it to aggregate - it just returned latest n items.

I have the following query that does the aggregation of all items' values, but how do I confine this to - let's say - 20 items, sorted by a date field?

```
http://mysearchdomain/index/type/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg_name1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_parent",
        "size": 2000000
      },

      "aggs": {
        "agg_name2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "myfield"
          },

          "aggs": {
            "agg_name3": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "fieldToAggregate"
              }
            }
          }

        }
      }

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: you can add filter in your aggregations. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html

Comment: @ArchitSaxena How does the filter limit the size of the aggregated dataset, and how does it sort? It doesn't seem to be able to do this, according to the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible, as far as I can gauge from the documentation. You're trying to filter on data that is already aggregated (per "agg_name1"), which seems to be the main issue; and `top_hits` will not work either on an already aggregated dataset.

Your best bet, as I see it, is making a `top_hits` aggregation request for each "agg_name1", which sadly would mean more requests (same amount as the amount of "agg_name1") you may have.